# Make async function return a Promise

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, google-sheets, promise, google-sheets-api

I have an async function, which I want to return a promise. If I wrap it inside a promise, it says something like await has to be inside async function.

```
async function accessSpreadsheet(first_name,last_name,email,phone) {
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth({
    client_email: creds.client_email,
    private_key: creds.private_key,
  });

  await doc.loadInfo(); // loads document properties and worksheets

  const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0]; // or use doc.sheetsById[id]
  console.log(sheet.title);
  await sheet.addRow({ "first name": first_name,"last name": last_name, email: email,phone:phone });
}
```

Comment: async functions always return a promise. Even if you return something that is not a promise, it will be implicitly wrapped in a promise and then returned.

Comment: The return value of an `async function` is a `Promise`. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: It doesnt console.log(sheet.title). What do I do

Comment: What does `doc.sheetsByIndex[0]` returns?

Comment: an excel sheet object, which has details of sheet title and sheet rows

Comment: Why do you think wrapping an async function with the promise will solve your problem? Your problem is somewhere else. Try wrapping the code in your function in `try-catch` block and see if there are any errors thrown during the execution of this function.

Comment: @player0 Questions tagged nodejs or python or any other language  should NOT be tagged with [tag:google-apps-script]( uses Internal api). They should be tagged with [tag:google-sheets-api](external api). See [tag info page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/google-sheets-api/info) for more details.